# Continual saving of data with hibernate in a while loop

Tags: mysql, jpa

I am reading from a file and trying to save all data using jpa into mysql db 
my readandLoad method looks like this

```
@Service
public class ReadLoadLog {

    @Autowired
    private LogbeanRepository logbeanRepository;

    public void readFile(LogBean logBean) throws IOException {

        Scanner read = new Scanner(
            new File(
                "/src/main/resources/access.txt"));

        while (read.hasNext()) { //checks if there is a valid token

            String string = read.nextLine();
            System.out.println(string);

            Scanner readFileByLine = new Scanner(string);

            while (readFileByLine.hasNext()) { //checks valid token if not then goes out of loop
                String[] split = readFileByLine.nextLine().split("\\|");

                logBean.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.parse(split[0], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")));
                logBean.setIp_address(split[1]);
                logBean.setRequest(split[2]);
                logBean.setStatus(split[3]);
                logBean.setUserAgent(split[4]);
            }
            logbeanRepository.save(logBean);
        }
    }
}
```

i am running this with spring boot using the commandLineRunner() i have the mysql properties declared in app.properties in my database i only get three new Ids but i have over a thousand data, when i click on execute select from table in my mysql workbench i get different datas but thesame three ids 1,2,3
so the data seems to be downloaded to db but now arranged according to the primary key i have set

```
'1', '2017-01-01 18:25:55', '192.168.97.208', '\"GET / HTTP/1.1\"', '200', '\"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Moto G (4) Build/NPJS25.93-14-8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.116 Mobile Safari/537.36\"'
'2', '2017-01-01 18:01:27', '192.168.45.70', '\"GET / HTTP/1.1\"', '200', '\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0\"'
'3', '2017-01-01 09:41:38', '192.168.87.47', '\"GET / HTTP/1.1\"', '200', '\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36\"'

@Entity
public class LogBean {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private LocalDateTime dateTime;

    private String ip_address;

    private String request;

    private String status;

    private String userAgent;
```

This is my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ParserprojectApplication implements CommandLineRunner   {

    @Autowired
    LogbeanRepository logbeanRepository;

    @Autowired
    ReadLoadLog readLoadLog;

    private Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ParserprojectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.debug("run(args)", args);

        LogBean logBean = new LogBean();
        readLoadLog.readFile(logBean);
    }
```

I want to get everydata that is read so i should be getting over a thousand data with unique primary key instead i am getting the data's but they all in ,1,2,3 keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a new instance of LogBean for each line you read in, otherwise it will overwrite the previous one.